# HTML button not sending SQL query to database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm trying to send a SQL command from a HTML button to copy contents of one table into another table, then delete the those contents from the original table. My SQL works if I run through PHPMyAdmin, but not from the button click. How do I get the button to process the query?

```
<?php include("datagrid/dataconfig.php"); ?>
<form action="Daily-Activity-Log.php" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" style="float:right;" class="btn btn-outline-success" name="dgrefresh"  onclick="refresh()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button>
</form>

<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");

    //REFRESH
        if(isset($_POST['dgrefresh'])){
            $refreshquery = "INSERT INTO `activityarchive` SELECT * FROM `activity` WHERE ActivityCompleted='1';
                                DELETE FROM `activity` WHERE ActivityCompleted='1'";

                $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $refreshquery);
                /*DEBUG MODE*/
                if($query_run)
              {
                echo '<script> alert("Data Saved"); </script>';
                header('Location: Daily-Activity-Log.php');
              }
              else {
                echo '<script> alert("Data not Saved"); </script>';
              }
            }
     ?>

<!-- REFRESH Script -->
<script>
  function refresh(){
    location.reload();
  }
</script>
```

Thank you Dharman for the link. I used the mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); command and found out that it wasn't completely talking to the DB. Once I added that it worked as expected.

Comment: The name of your actual php script is Daily-Activity-Log.php, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: Then you don't need your javascript function refresh().

Comment: It only purpose is to update the datagrid when the SQL query is ran.

Comment: When you'll click on your *input* type submit, all the page will be refreshed.

Comment: I removed it refresh script.

Comment: Thank you Dharman for the link. I used the mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); command and found out that it wasn't completely talking to the DB. Once I added that it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your 
    `<button type="submit">`
by an
    `<input type="submit">`

and delete
`onclick="refresh()"`.

Comment: I replaced the button with input, with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Write two separate queries and execute them.

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    //REFRESH
    if(isset($_POST['dgrefresh'])){
    $refreshquery = "INSERT INTO `activityarchive` SELECT * FROM `activity` WHERE ActivityCompleted='1';";
    $deleteData = "DELETE FROM `activity` WHERE ActivityCompleted='1'";

    $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $refreshquery);
    mysqli_query($con, $deleteData); //Execute delete query here
    /*DEBUG MODE*/
    if($query_run){
        echo '<script> alert("Data Saved"); </script>';
        header('Location: Daily-Activity-Log.php');
    }
    else{
        echo '<script> alert("Data not Saved"); </script>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I split the queries into two separate ones, still with the same result.

Comment: What is the name of php file, you have written this code?

Comment: Daily-Activity-Log.php. Everything is written in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

First, PHP is a backend language.
To execute you script, you've to point the action form attrib to the same page.

E.g:

```
//index.php
<form action="index.php">
...
```

So when your browser (ok, i mean server side ) a post request, it will execute your mysql query.

Comment: Everything is on Daily-Activity-Log.php, (form & php script).